# Setting groupby nunique to dataframe column

Tags: pandas

I have a groupby that I am trying to set as a new column within my dataframe, but when I set a column name to the result of the groupby its returns `NaN` as the value of each row. If the groupby is set to a new value and then printed the value returns the gropby values and the nunique for each. Is the issue I am facing due to some indexing that needs to be resolved on the dataframe?

**When set to column:**

```
merged_df['noramlized_values'] = merged_df.groupby(['be_hash'])['id'].nunique()

// normalized_values
// NaN
```

**When set to a new value:**

```
test = merged_df.groupby(['be_hash'])['id'].nunique()

// ij32ndshufho23nd 1
```

Data example

```
id  date    be_hash     unique_call_rank    normalized_calls    What I want
1   10/20/20    10171   1                       3                   1
1   10/20/20    10171   1                       3                   0
2   10/20/20    10171   2                       3                   1   
3   10/23/20    10171   3                       3                   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with both columns and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
merged_df['noramlized_values'] = np.where(merged_df.duplicated(['be_hash','id']), 0, 1)
print (merged_df)
   id      date  be_hash  unique_call_rank  normalized_calls  What I want  \
0   1  10/20/20    10171                 1                 3            1   
1   1  10/20/20    10171                 1                 3            0   
2   2  10/20/20    10171                 2                 3            1   
3   3  10/23/20    10171                 3                 3            1   

   noramlized_values  
0                  1  
1                  0  
2                  1  
3                  1
```

Comment: That works, but the result is slightly different than what I was looking for. I updated my question to reflect what this does with the slight adjustment of `[id]` to `[unique_call_rank]` and what I am looking to achieve. Basically any instance where there are duplicate `unique_call_ranks` it would count only one. Not sure if that is misleading from initial ask, but what I am looking to achieve.

Comment: @cphill - So there is one group from sample data `10171`, why is expected output `0` ? In output should be `2` ?

Comment: the `be_hash` can have duplicated values, which can be identified by both a duplicate `id` and duplicate `unique_call_rank` I'm looking to create a new boolean column per `be_hash` that uniquely counts `unique_call_rank` values and leave a `0` in the cases where there are duplicates after the first instance

Comment: @cphill - If is added new row `1   10/20/20    10171   1 ` in sample data to top row how looks expected output?

Comment: That would return as `0` for `What I Want` because a record already exists with the same attributes and is being counted as `1`